# Installation of ns2 in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu-11.04, ns2

i m trying to install ns2 in my ubuntu 11.04
but on installing any package the synaptic is giving error.

`E: /var/cache/apt/archives/ns2_2.35~RC6-3_amd64.deb: package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)`

Can anyone tell me what is the reason for this. this was not before i think i have made some changes please tell me how could i restore.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a 64 bit binary package on a 32-bit system.

You are probably running the 32-bit ubuntu version.

You can find more information about installing NS2 on ubuntu here : http://lukasz.chrost.com/gibbering/2-devel/11-installing-and-running-ns-2-on-ubuntu-710.html

Comment: synaptic is giving this error on installing any package
how could i resolve this and why it was not giving this before

Comment: You can check your ubuntu version and your CPU compatibility that way: [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-find-if-processor-is-64-bit-or-not/)